# Contextmenu plugin not work in modal. Bug in jsTree?

Tags: angularjs, jstree, bootstrap-modal

I am using [ngJsTree directive](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree) for [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/).

I have trouble where using it in modal.
I created [issue](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree/issues/50) for ngJsTree.
But i don't know, how reproduce this without angular directive (haven't skill without angular).

[image]

it's screen, where mouse right button doesn't work, as expected

**UPDATE**

I reproduced this for jsTree ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DkKcAhKf1SG99rEx279g?p=preview)).
piece of code:

```
 $(function () {
    // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "checkbox": {
            real_checkboxes: true,
            real_checkboxes_names: function (n) {
                var nid = 0;
                $(n).each(function (data) {
                    nid = $(this).attr("nodeid");
                });
                return (["check_" + nid, nid]);
            },
            two_state: true
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox", "contextmenu"]
    });
    // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.selected);
    });
    // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
    $('#jstreedemobutton').on('click', function () {
        $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
        $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
        $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
    });
});
```

Contextmenu is out of modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add in your css the following rule:

`.vakata-context {
   z-index: 1100
}`